# CakePHP: Shared Hosting Dilemma

Tags: cakephp, hosting, shared

I'm having trouble with uploading my cakePHP project on a shared hosting ( from hostgator ).
 Here is what I have done:
   I've organized my cake distribution like this:

- home/user/app
- home/user/cake/cake
- home/user/cake/vendors
- home/user/cake/.htaccess
- home/user/cake/index.php

  I have taken the content of webroot directory from app and put it in

  - home/user/public_html

  I've modified this file home/user/public_html/index.php ( the one that was in app/webroot )
  changing these lines like this:

  - define('ROOT', DS.'home'.DS.'user');
  - define('APP_DIR', 'app');
  - define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'home'.DS.'user'.DS.'cake');

  And that's about it.

  MY PROBLEM IS THE FOLLOWING:

  I have managed to deal with all the problems involved in the default index.php cakePHP page and I have a green and fully functional so to say, project. So when I access my "/", I get:

  "Your tmp directory is writable.

  The FileEngine is being used for caching. To change the config edit APP/config/core.php

  Your database configuration file is present.

  Cake is able to connect to the database."

  Now, I've created a model-view-controller with a mysql database background (like in the 15 min Blog Tutorial ), but when I'm trying to access some views ( e.g. /posts )...it gives me a blank page ( this worked perfect on my local machine virtual server apache ).

  What configuration am I missing ?

  Thank you.

EDIT: Apparently I had problems with the hosting. My URL was something like:

http://gator111.hostgator.com/~username/

and all I had to do was add an extra line in the webroot .htaccess:

RewriteBase /~username/

Thanks for the support.

Comment: setting your debug level to 2 in config/core.php might give you an error message

Comment: It is set to 2. I've even tried with 3, but no errors, just the blank page.

Comment: Check apache logs, that can give you a clue.

Comment: Try dumping out your cache folder, also.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is a life saver, I had the same problem that my host name comes with ~username. Now after adding the '`rewriteBase /~username/`', works like a charm.

However, before all these, I followed a youtube tutorial by jason talking about how to configure cakephp on shared hosting. Just paste it here in case it helps anybody.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GobWo1rIkE&tracker=False